# WooCommerce: Search products by title, category, tag or brand is not working

Tags: wordpress, search, woocommerce, categories, product

I have problem with woocommerce in query search product.
I want to search product with condition:

- **Like Product title**
- **In category**
- **In product tag**
- **In brand**

I could not search my product with the condition above

people can help me
thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [**free woocommerce plugin**](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-products-filter/), that enable for products a more complex search by custom filtering by:

- products categories,
- products attributes,
- products tags,
- products *custom* taxonomies
- products price.

This plugin has also an extension API for developers.

I think that is the right solution for you…